# Find partial match in Excel using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, vba

I thought I knew a lot about Excel, but I clearly still have a lot to learn. I'm trying to do a `VLOOKUP` formula with partial match to my worksheet named ***Metadata***.

**Formula**

`=VLOOKUP("*"&A7,Metadata!$A$1:$K$107009,4,0)`

***Sheet1***

[image]

**Sheet** ***Metadata***

[image]

If you look at the 4<sup>th</sup> column on ***Metadata*** there is *"CCSST ADDO"*, which partially matches *"ADDO Agency"* (in `Column A` on ***Sheet1***), but the above formula does not work; I just get an `#N/A` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To begin with `"*"&A7` will match `CCSST ADDO Agency` but not `CCSST ADDO`. Second, `VLOOKUP("*"&A7,Metadata!$A$1:$K$107009,4,0)` Will lookup the searched for value in the first column of `Metadata!$A$1:$K$107009` and return the corresponding value in the 4th column

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thank you the info, but what is the work around?

Comment: @TotsieMae, thanks for the editing

Comment: Does anyone have an answer for me?

Comment: The workaround is to use `Index/Match`. I don't think anyone will have an answer until you define your requirements more rigorously. For example, why would "CCSST ADDO" match "ADDO Agency" but not "Adderly Street"? (all have the substring "ADD").

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad , The names could of changed, but the still kept some part of the original name.

Comment: This does not add more rigour to the requirements. (VBA does not *understand* English (or any other human language) Perhaps the best way would be to have a table of the name pairs you can refer to?

Comment: I honestly don't think this is doable - at least with a formula. You'd run into the issue of having to iterate over every letter of each word and then possibly getting multiple matches for common letter combinations (e.g. *the*, *ett*, *ing*, etc.). I think you're ultimately attempting to find the cell with the highest match percentage of letters/words to the one you're comparing.